# A symbol like \hookleftarrow without the arrow?

Tags: symbols

There are [square hooks](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (e.g. `\lsqhook`), but that's not quite what I want. I'd like a version of [`\hookleftarrow`](https://docs.latexbase.com/symbols/hookleftarrow/) without the arrow. Is it possible to modify the `\hookleftarrow`, or `\hookrightarrow` symbols to get what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of `\hookleftarrow` is

```
\leftarrow\joinrel\rhook
```

and `\longleftarrow` is `\leftarrow\joinrel\relbar`. Ehi! We can use `\relbar`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% generally recommended

\newcommand{\hookleftline}{\DOTSB\relbar\joinrel\rhook}
\newcommand{\hookrightline}{\DOTSB\lhook\joinrel\relbar}

\begin{document}

$A\hookleftline B$

$A\hookrightline B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\DOTSB` command is for `amsmath`.

Comment: Ah! I can look at the [documentation of amsmath](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) to see how a symbol is defined, and then tweak that!

Comment: @user89 That's always the starting point

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to "build your own".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\Hook}{%
\raisebox{1.5pt}{\rotatebox{90}{\reflectbox{\resizebox{3pt}{\height}{$\mathsf{J}$}}}}}
\newcommand{\PicHook}{%
\begin{picture}(9,6)
\put(0,3){\line(1,0){7}}
\put(8,6){\oval(2,2)[r]}
\end{picture}}
\begin{document}
$\hookleftarrow$~\Hook~$A\Hook B$ 

$\hookleftarrow$~\PicHook~$A\PicHook B$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a "minimal" version in the sense that it does not require extra fonts, but it certainly not the most beautiful symbol on this planet.