# \looparrowright but without the arrow tip

Tags: symbols

What is the easiest way to typeset a symbol like \looparrowright, but without the arrow?

Is there a solution as easy as the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414030/a-symbol-like-hookleftarrow-without-the-arrow)?
I don't know where to look up the definition of \looparrowright, to see for myself whether I could achieve my desired symbol.

Comment: It's a different case: `\hookrightarrow` is composed with two gliphs, but `\looprightarrow` isn't. You can clip the symbol, though.

Comment: Just a info: `\DeclareMathSymbol{\looparrowright} {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"23}` found in `amssymb.dtx` at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts. No idea what that means, though.

Comment: Consider to accept one of the provided answers, I recommend to accept egreg's answer since it covers more situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can clip the symbol:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\leftloop}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\left@loop\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\left@loop}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\looparrowright}
  \smash{\clipbox{0 {-.1\height} {.35\width} {-.1\height}}{$\m@th#1{\looparrowright}$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\leftloop b_{c\leftloop d}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Code borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395049/4427

This means “cut nothing on the left, add a negative clip on the bottom, clip 35% of the width from the right, add a negative clip on the top”. Why negative clipping? Because the glyph slightly overshoots its bounding box. So I also smash the clipped symbol and set the height with the help of `\vphantom`.

Can we keep the round cap? Yes, by adding a clipped minus sign.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\leftloop}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\left@loop\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\left@loop}[2]{%
  \smash{\clipbox{0 {-.1\height} {.4\width} {-.1\height}}{$\m@th#1{\looparrowright}$}}%
  \clipbox{{0.8\width} 0 0 0}{$\m@th#1-$}%
  \mkern-1mu
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fboxrule=0.1pt\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{$\leftloop$}% just to see the bounding box

$a\leftloop b_{c\leftloop d}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

No need to add a phantom, because the minus sign has the right height and depth.

Comment: +1: I tried it myslef with the `adjustbox` package after I read your comment ("clip it"). The "round cap" is amazing.

Answer (score 5):

- Please go with eger's answer - I just was inspired by his comment and tried it myself.
- I use the `adjustbox` package.
- @pros Please indicate if my solution has some problems (apart from being too simplistic).
- This is a trial-and-error approach :).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \adjustbox{trim = 0 0 1 0, clip}{\fbox{Test $a$}} \fbox{Test $a$}
    \item \adjustbox{trim = 0 0 7 0, clip}{\fbox{$\looparrowright$}} \fbox{$\looparrowright$}
    \item \adjustbox{trim = 0 0 4 0, clip}{$\looparrowright$}
\end{itemize}

\newcommand{\myLoop}{\adjustbox{trim = 0 0 4 0, clip}{\ensuremath{\looparrowright}}}

\myLoop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why go for egreg's answer only? It's a good solution indeed, but I'm looking for the simplest one and yours looks more simple in terms of latex coding. Are there technical reasons to prefer egreg's solution over yours?

Comment: @frabala I am not sure, therefore I put "@pros Please indicate if my solution has some problems (apart from being too simplistic)." in the answer :).

Comment: I think you forgot `$...$` in the definition of `\myLoop`. @frabala This answer looks simpler but won't scale according to the current math style. The `\mathpalette` "complication" in egreg's answer does this. Of course, one could easily adapt this answer.

Comment: @campa I did not use `$$` in `\newcommand` on purpose. I just assum that teh commadn will be used in myth mode. Maybe I should add a `\ensuremath` command :).

Comment: *math mode, typo in my previous comment.

Comment: Uhm, my comment was due to the fact that your code throws an error on my system. But I can't check now, I'll look into it again tomorrow...

Comment: @campa Ahhh. I did not see the error message. On my system the output looked good. I have changed the code (\ensuremath). Thx for the hint.